# Play 2 - How to add a project (library) as a dependency

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-idea

My team is looking to re-architect one of our applications in Play2.  The application is split up into two web applications that sit on top of the same database: *client(read)* and *admin(read/write)*.

In the new architecture, we're looking to build two Play2 servers that expose a REST API.  There will be two single-page AngularJS apps sitting in front of each.  But both servers share common functionality.  So we're looking to build a common library which will expose the data access layer (models and DAOs).  Each server will have its own set of services.

**Client (REST server): read**

- Client-services
- Common-library

**Admin (REST server): read/write (full CRUD)**

- Admin-services
- Common-library

I'm using IntelliJ 13 and am having a hard time setting this up.  I've taken a look at the following sources:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/SBTSubProjects

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project

I believe what I want is add the library type dependency as a (Import Module...), in contrast to adding a module to the parent project

- myProject

  - app
  - conf
  - public
- myLibrary

  - src

    - main

      - java
      - scala
- project

  - Build.scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by abandoning SBT as my dependency/build tool.  I ended up using Maven via a plugin (http://nanoko-project.github.io/maven-play2-plugin/maven/release/index.html).  The plugin works great.  Maven is used as in traditional Java applications.

I created a three pom.xml files for each "project" (Client, Admin, shared library), and an additional pom.xml for parent.  Nothing new here.  Just your typical Maven setup for multi-project dependencies.

Like I said, the Play2 Maven Plugin works great!  I highly recommend it for complicated Play2 applications involving project dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using IntelliJ 13, you have access to the built in SBT importing; unfortunately **this can't be done on an existing project**. You can, however, import a project from an SBT Build file, and then migrate over any project settings  from the .idea folder (assuming you're using Directory-based Projects).

With that said, it sounds like you also could use some clarification on setting up the Build.scala, so let's dig into that.

### Example Play2 Configuration:

I'm going to go ahead and assume you've already created the two Play projects with *play new*.

We want to set up the project like this:

- ClientPlayProject

  - App
  - Conf
  - Public
- AdminPlayProject

  - App
  - Conf
  - Public
- SharedLibrary

  - src

    - main
    - test
- Project

  - Build.scala

Assuming a layout like this, here's an example of what a Build.scala might look like:

```
import play.Project._
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._


object BuildSettings {
  val appOrganization = "com.example"

  val appVersion = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

  val commonResolvers = Seq(
    // Your common resolvers here
  )

  val commonSettings = Seq(
    organization := appOrganization,
    // Other shared settings
    resolvers ++= commonResolvers
  )

  val commonDeps = Seq(
    // Shared Dependencies for all 3 projects here.
  )

  val adminDeps = Seq(
    // Admin dependencies
  ) ++ commonDeps


  val clientDeps = Seq(
    // Client Dependencies
  ) ++ commonDeps

  val libraryDeps = Seq(
    // Library Deps
  ) ++ commonDeps
}

object Build extends Build {

  import BuildSettings._

  lazy val LibraryProject = Project("SharedLibrary", file("SharedLibrary"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= libraryDeps)

  lazy val AdminProject = play.Project("AdminPlayProject", appVersion, adminDeps, path = file("AdminPlayProject"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= adminDeps)
    .dependsOn(LibraryProject)

  lazy val ClientProject = play.Project("ClientPlayProject", appVersion, clientDeps, path = file("ClientPlayProject"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .dependsOn(LibraryProject)

  lazy val aggregatedProjects = Seq[ProjectReference](
    LibraryProject,
    AdminProject,
    ClientProject
  )

  lazy val root = Project("Root", file("."))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .aggregate(aggregatedProjects: _*)
}
```

As soon as you've got your Build.scala all squared away, just do the Import Project step in IntelliJ and it'll get your code completion all squared away and good to go.

As a note,  you may want to break parts of this up into other .scala files and import them; perhaps a Dependencies object, a Resolvers object, etc. It really depends on the complexity level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Question - are all of those projects defined within a root project OR are they completely separate?

Comment: In this example, they all live in the root project; you might be able to distribute the build settings out to subprojects but I'm not familiar with how you'd go about doing that. 

I'm also sort of dubious on the benefits of such; I think it's probably preferable to spread settings amongst multiple files in the root Project folder; even in a project as big as the Play Framework itself, they've got all the definitions and settings in the root Project folder.

Comment: We plan to have the Client and Admin on their own server (so their loads don't effect each other) but will have a common layer of code (DAOs and such).  For that reason, when I create a Play project for each, I'd like to have a library in which both can share to avoid duplicating code and versioning concerns.  So you're saying this isn't possible to achieve in Play/SBT? I wonder if creating soft-links on the shared modules would solve this problem.